# Создание get и set методов при помощи анотаций в Java?

Tags: java

Можно ли создать get и set для private полей в Java классе используя какую-либо библиотеку.

Явно не определяя их в коде, например при помощи аннотаций?

Может Spring(boot) имеет данную возможность?

```
public static class SomeClass {
    private Integer property1;
    private String  property2;
    private String  propertyN;
}
```

Comment: здесь скорее что-то вроде [`lombok`](https://projectlombok.org/) подойдет

Comment: пишите сразу на Kotlin тогда уж =), генерация исходников это сделка с дьяволом, нужно понимать на что вы подписываетесь =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, круто же :-) исходники которые генерируют исходники!

Comment: @Grundy круто, только билд инженеры матерятся потом

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, _билд инженеры_ должны страдать :-D

Comment: @Grundy ну так то я не отрицаю, я только хотел сказать что минусы тоже есть

Answer (score 4):

Судя по видео на [главной странице](https://projectlombok.org/), в данном случае подойдет lombok, и аннотации [`@Getter`/`@Setter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter)

Пример из справки

Код с использованием аннотаций:

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public class GetterSetterExample {
  /**
   * Age of the person. Water is wet.
   * 
   * @param age New value for this person's age. Sky is blue.
   * @return The current value of this person's age. Circles are round.
   */
  @Getter @Setter private int age = 10;

  /**
   * Name of the person.
   * -- SETTER --
   * Changes the name of this person.
   * 
   * @param name The new value.
   */
  @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED) private String name;

  @Override public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s (age: %d)", name, age);
  }
}
```

Соответствующий код на Java

```
public class GetterSetterExample {
  /**
   * Age of the person. Water is wet.
   */
  private int age = 10;

  /**
   * Name of the person.
   */
  private String name;

  @Override public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s (age: %d)", name, age);
  }

  /**
   * Age of the person. Water is wet.
   *
   * @return The current value of this person's age. Circles are round.
   */
  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  /**
   * Age of the person. Water is wet.
   *
   * @param age New value for this person's age. Sky is blue.
   */
  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  /**
   * Changes the name of this person.
   *
   * @param name The new value.
   */
  protected void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как раз сейчас изучаю. Все правильно подойдет lombok, но все намного проще - пример кода:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Taco { 
  private String name; 
  private List<String> ingredients;
}
```

Аннотация [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) создает все что вам нужно.

Comment: _Аннотация @Data создает все что вам нужно._ и возможно немножко больше :)

Comment: А также аннотация "@Getter" "@Setter" https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter, если вам ненужна вся та чепуха которую генерирует "@Data"